# Android listen for new downloads

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I am trying to listen for changes(new file created) in default download directory.

My first option was to have a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` but turns out it needs `android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS` which is level 2 `[Signature permision]`.

Now I am thinking to use [FileObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) on default download directory and listen for created file events and sent an intent.
I am worried that my background service hosting `FileObserver` will be killed by the system under peak usage.

Is there any other option to listen for new downloads?